# WPF Canvas as content inside button is not visible if adjacent element fills the space inside a container (DockPanel, Grid)

Tags: wpf, button, canvas

I have a button like so:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
      <Grid Width="81" Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
      <Button  Width="120"  DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="Button" ></TextBlock>
          <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0" >
            <TextBlock Text="I want to break free" />
          </Canvas>
        </Grid>
      </Button>
    </DockPanel>
  </StackPanel>
```

In this case the canvas content will not get rendered and it's content won't be visible.
If I however change the Grid lengths from 81 to 80 it works.

It will also work in this scenario:

```
    <Grid Width="200">
      <Grid Width="81" Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" />
      <Button  Width="120"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="Button" ></TextBlock>
          <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0" >
            <TextBlock Text="I want to break free" />
          </Canvas>
        </Grid>
      </Button>
    </Grid>
```

The Canvas will also work if not inside a button:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Height="42">
      <Grid Width="81" Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
      <Canvas Margin="120,0,0,0"  >
        <TextBlock  Text="I want to break free" />
      </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
  </StackPanel>
```

Why is it behaving like that inside a button? How can be this fixed to the wanted behavior of showing the canvas?

Comment: Don't set the `Width` of the `StackPanel` to `200` if you want it to be wider? Why are you even using a `StackPanel`?

Comment: It is for showing the behavior, that it disappears if you have `Width` wider than the parent container `Width`.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour for a panel.

Comment: @mm8 so why does the panel behave differently while the canvas is not in a button? See last example.